# How to format string with spaces in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

I need help with string.format to insert three spaces every three digit. This digit is at a fixed length at 12 digits.

```
var membershipNo = string.Format("{0:### ### ### ###}", "123123123123");
Console.WriteLine(membershipNo);
```

Result: 123123123123

Expected: 123 123 123 123

Comment: `0:### ### ### ###` is a numeric format string, not a string format. Where are the digits in `membershipNo` coming from? If they're always digits why are you storing them as a string not an long?

Comment: Also - what result you expect for `"000123123123"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of formating doesn't work for an instance of `string`. Consider passing an interger (or any other numeric type) and it will work as expected

```
int number = 123123123123;
var membershipNo = string.Format("{0:### ### ### ###}", number);
Console.WriteLine(membershipNo);
```